# how to connect to signal from one class to a slot in another?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2, pyside6

How to connect to `myQCustomQWidget.connectButton` to `exampleQMainWindow.setNewText`

If the signal/slot are in the same class, i.e `exampleQMainWindow` I can simply connect them like this:

```py
self.button.clicked.connect(self.setNewText)
```

But if they are in different classes, How can I connect them?

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class QCustomQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel = QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel = QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel = QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)
        # setStyleSheet
        self.textUpQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
        ''')
        self.textDownQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        ''')

        self.openButton = QPushButton()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.openButton, 1)

    def setButton(self, index):
        self.openButton.setText(index)

    def connectButton(self, index): # <-----
        self.openButton.clicked.connect()

    def setTextUp(self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown(self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon(self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))


class exampleQMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Create QListWidget
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.setRowCount(6)
        for index, name, icon, btname in [
            (1, 'text1', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "alpha"),
            (2, 'text2', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "beta"),
            (3, 'text3', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "gamma"),
            (4, 'text4', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "delta")
            ]:
            # Create QCustomQWidget
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(str(index))
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setButton(str(btname))
            myQCustomQWidget.button_row = index

            myQCustomQWidget.connectButton()  # how to connect it to setNewText ?

            self.table.setCellWidget(index, 1, myQCustomQWidget)
            self.table.setRowHeight(index,90)


    def setNewText(self): # <----------
        print("test") 



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.resize(800,512)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `a` is the table. It should be `a = self.table.cellWidget(index, 1)` and then `a.setTextUp(...)`. Note, though, that your approach is quite dangerous and discouraged (other than conceptually wrong), as you're using a global reference in the lamda, and also accessing a parent object from a child (which violates the hierarchy of the structure). Instead, create a custom signal for your widget and connect it to the fuction whenever you create a new instance.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is confusing. I've edited the post to make it clearer what I want to achieve.My problem is how to create a custom signal to call >def setNewText(self):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom signal that emits the index, then connect it from the instance that creates the widget, not the other way around.

```py
class QCustomQWidget(QWidget):
    clicked = Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, index, name, icon, btnName, parent=None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        # ...
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.emitClicked)
        self.setTextUp(str(index + 1))
        self.setTextDown(name)
        self.setIcon(icon)
        self.setButton(btnName)
    # ...

    def emitClicked(self):
        self.clicked.emit(self.index)


class exampleQMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        data = [
            ('text1', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "alpha"),
            ('text2', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "beta"),
            ('text3', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "gamma"),
            ('text4', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "delta")
            ]
        self.table.setRowCount(len(data))
        for index, (name, icon, btname) in enumerate(data):
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget(index, name, icon, btnname)
            myQCustomQWidget.clicked.connect(self.setNewText)

            self.table.setCellWidget(index, 1, myQCustomQWidget)
            self.table.setRowHeight(index, 90)

    def setNewText(self, index):
        print(index)
```

Note that signal connections of child objects should usually be done by a parent object, not the other way around. Also, you should not use global references, especially for these situations, otherwise you might have unexpected behavior or exceptions caused by missing references.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible ways:

1. 

```py
def connectButton(self): # <-----
    self.openButton.clicked.connect(exampleQMainWindow.setNewText)
```

And change this method to static since you don't use the instance (self).

```py
@staticmethod
def setNewText(): # <----------
    print("test")
```

---

2. 

If this wasn't a `staticmethod` you would want to pass a instance to the class that you want to connect to in your case it would be:

```py
class QCustomQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main_window = parent  # not required, just to understand better.
    # ...
    def connectButton(self): # <-----
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.parent.setNewText)
```

---

3. 

**Considered best practice**. Create signals in child and in the parent connect to the method you want.

Example based on your code:

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal

class QCustomQWidget(QWidget):
    ask_set_new_text = Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel = QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel = QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel = QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)
        # setStyleSheet
        self.textUpQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
        ''')
        self.textDownQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        ''')

        self.openButton = QPushButton()
        # self.openButton.setText("open")
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.openButton, 1)

    def setButton(self, index):
        self.openButton.setText(index)

    def connectButton(self): # <-----
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ask_set_new_text.emit())

    def setTextUp(self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown(self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon(self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))


class exampleQMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Create QListWidget
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.setRowCount(6)
        for index, name, icon, btname in [
            (1, 'text1', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "alpha"),
            (2, 'text2', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "beta"),
            (3, 'text3', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "gamma"),
            (4, 'text4', 'g:\downloads\coffee-icon.png', "delta")
            ]:
            # Create QCustomQWidget
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(str(index))
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.ask_set_new_text.connect(self.setNewText)
            #myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(icon) #just image can be ignored
            myQCustomQWidget.setButton(str(btname))
            myQCustomQWidget.button_row = index

            myQCustomQWidget.connectButton()# how to connect it to setNewText ?

            self.table.setCellWidget(index, 1, myQCustomQWidget)
            self.table.setRowHeight(index,90)

    def setNewText(self): # <----------
        print("test") 



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.resize(800,512)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: 1. connecting to a global reference is discouraged (if the class is imported, it will never work and will raise an exception), and the connection should also not be done by the child object; 2. CamelCase (aka CapWords) means that also the first letter is capitalized, and it's actually common. You're referring to mixedCase, which PEP8 [*does* allow](//peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names): "mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that’s already the prevailing style"; since it *is* prevailing in Qt, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it, and is also more consistent.

Comment: @musicamante 1. What do you mean by "a global reference"? And it sure does work for me. 2. Thank you I will edit the post, though IMO most of Qt for python users use snake case

Comment: 1. `exampleQMainWindow` is a global reference: if the class was used in a module, which should properly use the `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` to create the application, show the widget and start the event loop, it will raise an exception, since `exampleQMainWindow` would be only declared in *that* block; I never said that it doesn't work, but that that practice is discouraged; 2. I've seen both cases and it's impossible to get reliable statistics, but that's not the point: as said, there is absolutely *nothing wrong* with using mixedCase as long as it's done with awareness; it's obviously->

Comment: ->a matter of choice, and nobody could tell "you cannot do it". In my earlier days with Qt I thought it would be better to use snake case for custom functions (including custom subclasses), but after some time I found it very confusing: I had snake case for my own objects and mixedCase for the Qt ones, and seeing *both* standards in my code was actually annoying and *extremely* distracting: I always had to think if I was using a custom class or a (subclass of an) existing one before recalling the function/attribute name and finally typing the correct one. Style consistency is *very* important.